# how to updatecell in sheets with python from a for loop

Tags: python, variables, google-sheets, python-3.8

with all the import necessary, I have this code:

```
  # Get list of plants
plants = client.get_plant_list()

# Iterate the plant list and print all assets therein
for plant in plants:

    # Get list of assets
    response = client.get_asset_list(organization_id=client.organization_id)
    if len(response) == 0:
        print('No assets in this plant')
    else:
        for asset in response:
            a=(asset["assetName"],':',asset["lastSyncTimeStamp"])
        cell_list=sheet.range('A1:A60')
        for cell in cell_list:
            cell.value =(asset["assetName"])
        sheet.update_cells(cell_list)
return True
```

There are several assets with several information for which I only want "assetName" and "lastSyncTimeStamp".

The cells update but the problem is that all the cells got update with the information of one asset like it doesn't take the information of all assets.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Why do you `a=(asset["assetName"],':',asset["lastSyncTimeStamp"])`. `a` is never used again. I think you mainly did your indentation wrong. `asset["assetName"]` for example is being executed outside the for loop `asset` was defined in. I can only guess, but what i think you want to do is this:

```
cell_list=sheet.range('A1:A60')
for i, asset in enumerate(response):
    cell_list[i].value =(asset["assetName"])
sheet.update_cells(cell_list)
```

You might want to revisit some of the python tutorial pages.

Comment: it returns this error cell_list[i].value=(asset["assetName"])
NameError: name 'cell_list' is not defined